# Possible to construct JSON using bean class and annotations?

Tags: spring-boot

Expected response:

```json
{
  "messageHeader": {
    "serviceId": "SPECTRUM_MOBILE",
    "requestType": "MNO",
    "referenceNumber": "345700543345333434323433449793331996"
  },
  "data": {
    "code": "400",
    "reason": "Bad Request",
    "message": [
      {
        "responseCode": "ERR25",
        "description": "Duplicate request. This request has already been processed"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to construct this json using bean class and annotations.

Note:`referenceNumber`,`responseCode`,`description` values dynamically need to set and remaining all default values.

Comment: What have you tried? You can start with [ObjectMapper](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: Any possible ways other than objectMapper??